# Partitioning a raid array (RAID 5)

Tags: hard-drive, raid-5

I want to partition my RAID 5 array to put a linux swap on it. Does partitioning a raid array affect performance of the overall system? Are there any disadvantages of doing it?

Comment: @Moab I have a SSD for my OS. That wasnt the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; partitioning a raid array has no affect on performance, when done correctly.  Older partitioning tools were not careful about alignment and so they could create partitions that were not aligned to the stripe width, but up to date tools should handle this automatically.

Also I would suggest using LVM to manage the raid array instead of a conventional partition table.  It provides much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

RAID 5 doesn't handle small random writes very well - it's a relatively slow operation on a RAID 5 array - and so having your swap space there may hit system performance quite a bit.

Comment: choosing a proper chunk size can improve write performance...https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#RAID-5

Comment: Im intending to dual boot and under linux I wont be doing anything heavy. Will partitioning the drive affect performance even when the swap is not in use?